# Issue access to routes

Tags: laravel

How can Laravel not access the `confirm` and `password` pages after logging in? When after logging in, the user writes login in the address bar, and then it redirects to the home page. Now, after logging in, if we write `confirm` and `password`, it redirects to the home page.

On the page `confirm`, enter the confirmation code after the mobile number.

On the page `password`, enter the password.

```
Route::get('/confirm', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\MobileController::class, 'confirm'])->name('confirm');
Route::get('/password', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\MobileController::class, 'password'])->name('password');
```

I tried these codes in middleware but it is not working.

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, string ...$guards): Response
{
    $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;
    foreach ($guards as $guard) {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            if ($request->is('confirm') || $request->is('password')) {
                return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: it is impossible to answer based on the details provided

Answer (score -1):

#### Simple way is to add auth checker in method

```
class MobileController extends Controller{
     public function confirm(Request $request){
         if(\Auth::check()){
             return redirect()->route("home");
         }

         //other logics will goes here
     }

}
```

It has more options to achieve it, you may use middleware as well....
but above one is more simpler way.